# Casting to a Generic Type in Haxe

Tags: generics, haxe

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

I've done some digging and worked off of Laurence Taylor's answer. I'm almost there, but it appears it doesn't work with *recursive* wrapping. Here's an updated runnable code snippet that shows the problem (this time using my classes because I don't want to redefine everything)

[New runnable code sample](http://try.haxe.org/#Fd111).

Specifically, notice that `{t : 3}` (correctly) binds to an equitable the first time, but while `{t : {t : 3}}` (also correctly) binds to an equitable, the nested `{t : 3}` binds to a nonequitable. How is it possible that the same objects `t1` and `t2` bind to `Equitable` the first time, but `NonEquitable` the second time?

---

**Question v1:**

I'm chugging through Haxe and have reached a point that simplifies to this:

```
interface SelfReferringInterface<X> {
    public function doStuff(x : X) : Void;
}

class A {
    private var x : Int;
    public function new(x : Int){this.x = x;}

    public function toString() {return Std.string(x);}
}

class B implements SelfReferringInterface<B> {
    private var x : Int;

    public function new (x : Int){this.x = x;}

    public function doStuff(b : B) {
        trace(this + " and " + b);
    }

    public function toString() { return Std.string(x);}
}
```

Essentially, I have a bunch of classes (of which `A` and `B` are just two), some of which implement `SelfReferringInterface` on themselves (as `B` does), and others that do not implement it.

Then I have a Generic class that can wrap any type:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    private var t : T;
    public function new(t : T) {this.t = t;}
}
```

I would like to add a method to `GenericClass<T>` that, if it's `T` is an implementation of `SelfReferringInterface` will call doStuff, otherwise has some other default behavior:

```
class GenericClass<T> {
    private var t : T;
    public function new(t : T) {this.t = t;}

    public function doStuffOrTrace(t2 : T) {
         //if t instanceof SelfReferringClass, call t.doStuff(t2)
         //otherwise call trace(t) and ignore t2
    }
}
```

Such that the following test method does the following.

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        new GenericClass<A>(new A(3)).doStuffOrTrace(new A(4));//Expect 3
        new GenericClass<B>(new B(1)).doStuffOrTrace(new B(2));//Expect 1 and 2
    }
}
```

Is implementing `doStuffOrTrace(..)` at all possible? I have control over all of the classes but I'm trying to avoid altering `A` and `B` to make this possible. I can add to `SelfReferringInterface` or `GenericClass` as necessary. Ideas?

---

I've done some digging and it appears (due to covariance useages) that I'd rather `SelfReferringInterface<X>` be a *typedef* rather than an *interface*. I'm still stuck for implementing `doStuffOrTrace(..)`, but maybe this opens new avenues?

Comment: One thing I'd try is explicitly typing the output of wrap, there are some ambiguities around type resolution on generic types.  


You shouldn't really have to call wrap explicitly in the first place, given that abstract constructors should be called implicitly, and you can avoid the problem of Equatable<Equatable<T>> altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Best write an enum that has both cases, wrap that in an abstract and write @:from functions for each case, and use that as the input to doStuffOrTrace.

In normal use, calling the function will cause the invocation of the correct abstract constructor, and then you can use a switch internally to differentiate.

*Edit

```
@:from static public function fromHasInterface<T>(v:SelfReferringInterface<T>):HasInterfaceOrNot<T>{
  return THasInterface(v);
}
enum HasInterfaceOrNotT<T>{
  THasInterface(v:SelfReferringInterface<T>);
  THasNotInterface(v:Dynamic);
}
```

see running code [here](http://try.haxe.org/#482dc)

Comment: I can give that a shot.. could you add an example of valid use of @:from syntax? That's new to me

Comment: Thank you so much! I worked with your code and it's 90% working, but I'm hitting some trouble with recursive calls. See my updated question

Answer (score 1):

You could implement doStuffOrTrace using Std.is to determine the type of t and cast it to the SelfReferringInterface :

```
public function doStuffOrTrace(t2 : T) {
    if(Std.is(t, SelfReferringInterface)){
        var castedT = cast(t, SelfReferringInterface<Dynamic>);
        castedT.doStuff(t2);
    }else{
        trace(t);
    }
}
```

The problem is you never explicitely use the toString method, so it will be stripped away by the compiler (dce) and the trace(t) will output '[object]'

You can prevent that by adding @:keep metadata to the methods but since 
you cannot modify A and B, you can disable dce with the `-dce no` or `-dce std` compiler flag

Here is the try.haxe snippet : http://try.haxe.org/#40402